# How to read json with backslashes with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm calling 3rd party API and receiving as a response json:

{\"name\":\"name \\"A\\" and other\",\"id\":1}

If I try to map it like that I'm getting sure that:

```
 Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

How could I map it with jackson? Should I remove backslashes with regex? Like every \" -> " and \\" -> \"

Answer (score 1):

That is not well formed. What are you planning to do looks fine

Answer (score 0):

File a bug against whoever is producing this broken output; it is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

{\"name\":\"name A and other\",\"id\":1}, this is the valid form of JSON or
{"name":"name A and other","id":1} it is also valid.

If this is not possible to do it, ask your vendor to validate the JSON structure